# Emgu.CV can't load dll's

Tags: c#, asp.net, emgucv

I have an ASP.NET application that uses Emgu.CV for image processing.
All worked fine until today morning... Till then I am getting the error

> {"Unable to load DLL 'opencv_core249': Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"}

That means something like "Couldn't find the specified module"

when accessing a class from Emgu.CV. The ASP.NET application is beeing compiled as a x86 dll.
This is how the output folder looks like:
[image]

the folder "x86" contains all 22 dll from opencv, while the folder lib contains the dll "Emgu.CV.dll".
Strange thing is it worked until now, so something must have changed that broke it. I have tried Clean solution, rebuild solution with no success. I've been on this problem the whole day now, I'm loosing patience :(

EDIT:
This is what DependencyWalker says:
[image: Missing dependencies]

Comment: This is strange. After restarting my computer (it had some updates to install) it works again on my local IIS. However when I try to start it hitting F5 from visual studio 2013 it still throws that error...

Comment: Can no one help me on this topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days the error disappeared again.

Not sure what caused it. Maybe some bug in Visual Studio not loading all necessary dll's when debugging using the built in web-server.